# internal links and slimScroll, scroll bar doesn't move to the right position

Tags: jquery, slimscroll, internal-link

I'm using the slimScroll plugin on my website, but when i click to one internal link the scroll bar doesn't move. The content moving to the right position, only the bar stay on the top. Any idea for that?

Comment: Here is a sample:http://jsfiddle.net/rgmrw/343/

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with resizing and maintaining the scrollbar position a little while ago. 
The solution I found was to calculate the current bar position and scroll manually.

$('/* scroll object */').slimScroll({ scrollTo: /* Your value */ });

In your case however you will need to figure out the position which I'm going to guess you already have since your already moving the inner contents.